# Edit Animated SVG File in Adobe Illustrator and keep Animation

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, animation

I have an animated SVG that I would like to edit. The edit is very simple and I only want to change some text.

I can open the SVG correctly in Illustrator and make the change, but when I save it and view it in my web browser the animation no longer works.

Is there another package I am best off using to edit SVG files without losing the animation?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is changing some text, maybe you could edit the SVG in a text editor?

Answer (score 2):

It is very rare, to find editors that allow for full data roundtripping. In general Inkscape is a bewtter SVG editor since thats what it was built to be, whereas Illustrator is a EPS/PDF editor in its core.

That said there is a high chance that the data does not survive Inkscape. In those cases its just better to do the thing in a text editor.